# The result of using the catboostclassifier model's output python file to predict is different from the result of using model to predict directly

Tags: catboost

I want to verify that the predicted results from the exported file are consistent with those predicted directly.

I use the output Python file with the model description of catclassifier to predict result:

[image]

But the result which is predicted directly is 2.175615211102761. It is verified that this is true for multiple data. I want to know why and how to solve it.

`float_sample` and `cat_sample` look like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Supplementary question: the results predicted by using the model file described in Python language provided by the catboost tutorial are different from those predicted directly by the model